# EM::Synchrony.defer with fiber aware database call causes FiberError exception

Tags: ruby, eventmachine, fibers, em-synchrony

I'm trying to use EM-Synchrony for concurrency in an application and have come across an issue with my use of deferred code and Fibers.

Any calls to the database within either EM.defer or EM::Synchrony.defer results in the application crashing with the error `can't yield from root fiber`

Below is a very trimmed down runnable example of what I'm trying to accomplish. The first print works and displays `[:first, 1]` but the second is where I crash with the error mentioned above.

```
require 'mysql2'
require 'em-synchrony/activerecord'
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => 'em_mysql2',
  :username => 'user',
  :password => 'pass',
  :host => 'localhost',
  :database => 'app_dev',
  :pool => 60
)
class User < ActiveRecord::Base; end
EM.synchrony do
  p [:first, User.all.count]
  EM::Synchrony.defer do
    p [:second, User.all.count]
  end
end
```

My first thought was perhaps the Fiber.current and Fiber.yield within EM::Synchrony.defer meant I could fix the problem with an extra Fiber.new call

```
EM::Synchrony.defer do
  Fiber.new do
    p [:second, User.all.count]
  end.resume
end
```

This fails to run as well but this time I get the error `fiber called across threads`.

Comment: You seem to lack the finishing call to `EventMachine.stop` just before `EM.synchrony` loop end.

Comment: Adding EM.stop to the block does not change the outcome of the either code snippet.